# How to connect to a server hosted on an Azure virtual machine?

Tags: azure, ravendb, windows-server-2012, azure-virtual-machine

I'm running a RavenDB server on a virtual machine on Azure using port 8080. I can access it on localhost:8080 when I log into the virtual machine.

I added endpoint (public: 8080, private: 8080) on manage.windowsazure.com. However, when I try to access the server remotely through some web browser, it says it can't be found.

What else should I do? I'm running Windows Server 2012 on the virtual machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally this equates to a firewall issue on the Windows Server virtual machine. Did you make sure you have a rule allowing for incoming tcp traffic on port 8080?